# Использование элементов одной формы другой формой[Дизайнер форм]

Tags: pascal, .net, pascalabc.net

Есть вопрос. У меня две формы. На первой есть текстбокс к кнопочка. На второй - просто кнопка. Я сделал переход с первой формы на другую. При нажатии на второй форме кнопки в текстбоксе первой форме должно отображатся слово "Привет". Можно ли так сделать? И вообще можно ли связывать элементы одной формы с другой?

Comment: В чем сложность?

Comment: @Sin2p, вы самостоятельно изучаете язык? или у вас занятия какие-то в техникуме/вузе?

Comment: @teanЫЧ у нас занятия в техникуме, но они такие, что приходится половину информации узнавать самому. А сейчас я работаю над проектом к практике и даже большей половины, которую мы изучали - в проекте не используется. Поэтому от меня так много вопросов

Comment: @Sin2p, просто вы задаете вопросы по основным вещам, которые вам __обязаны__ были объяснить на занятиях.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И так, у вас есть две формы.
Чтобы связать одну форму/модуль с другим, надо у неё либо в разделе **interface** либо **implementation** (в зависимости от того, для чего вы связываете их) написать ключевое слово **uses** и после него написать название формы/модуля. После этого на *главной* форме можно будет использовать **public** элементы *побочной* формы.

---

Например, у вас есть public процедура на form1:

```
...
procedure Form1.WriteTextToTextBox();
begin
  TextBox1.text:= 'Привет!';
end;
...
```

Тогда на form2 надо сделать:

```
...
implementation
uses
form1; //тут надо название модуля указать
...
procedure Form2.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  form1.WriteTextToTextBox(); // тут обращение к форме происходит по ее имени name
end;
...
```

Comment: @teanЫЧ Вообщем опишу что хотел: у меня есть кнопка удаления. При ее нажатии я хотел вывести предупреждение типа: Точно удалить запись? 

Хотел сделать такое через новую форму, думал там сделать кнопку "Вернутся" и "Да". При нажатии да - удалялась запись. Это как то можно сделать?

Или еще один вариант: как то при нажатии вывести в текстбокс что то типа "Удалить запись?" и при повторном нажатии запись удалялась.

Что лучше?

Comment: Посмотрите этот материал: http://www.delphibasics.ru/MessageDlg.php  
не знаю, правда, как он отработает в pascalabc.net